# Jake task firing complete before completion of async task

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jake

I am testing Jake out as a possible replacement for Rake on a primarily javascript project. Now one thing that I am finding as odd is that the completion event is being triggered BEFORE the event has completed.

Here is an example:

```
task('some_task_1', {async: true}, function () {
    console.log("|- Doing something");

    var execCallback = function() {
        console.log("  |- Done something");
        complete();
    };

    setTimeout(execCallback, 2000);
});

task('some_task_2', {async: true}, function () {
    console.log("|- Doing something else");

    var execCallback = function() {
        console.log("  |- Done something else");
        complete();
    };

    setTimeout(execCallback, 2000);
});

task('task_runner', {async: true}, function () {
    var firstTask = jake.Task['some_task_1'];
    var secondTask = jake.Task['some_task_2'];

    firstTask.addListener("complete", function() { secondTask.invoke(); });
    secondTask.addListener("complete", function() { complete(); });

    firstTask.invoke();
});

task('default', function () {
    jake.Task['task_runner'].invoke();
});
```

I would have expected that the output would be:

```
|- Doing something
   |- Done something
|- Doing something else
   |- Done something else
```

However what I actually get is:

```
|- Doing something
|- Doing something else
   |- Done something
   |- Done something else
```

So is there some magic around how the async should be working in Jake? as it seems to be somehow firing a complete event before its actually finished the exec.

== EDIT ==

Just so there is no confusion I am using version 0.5.16 of Jake
https://github.com/mde/jake

== EDIT 2 ==

Have posted another example which now should show the exact issue in a clearer way as it seems to be related to tasks within tasks which are async.

Comment: Googling Node Jake nets many different, but similar results.  Can you provide a documentation link, or a repository name on github.  Your callbacks and such look reasonable, assuming you are using the library correctly, in particular that addListener, and invoke function as one would assume.

Comment: It is literally just a simple local jake project I knocked up a couple of hours ago. The actual project compiles a typescript file to javascript, but the code above is just the same. So there is unfortunately no github link or anything... I did try googling first but there was no direct correlation between the posts and my issue, most were about how to do sequenced builds using 3rd party libs. Everything *seems* fine to me, just doesn't run as I would have expected :(

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a change of behaviour (not sure if it's bug or feature) between node 0.8 to 0.10. Jake tasks that were executing sequentially in 0.8.14 (with async:true) seem to start running concurrently in 0.10.x

Try uninstalling node 0.10, and install 0.8 instead.

Comment: I'm running Node v0.10.12, and the minimal example works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this locally with the same Jake (v0.5.16). I had to correct the syntax -- you need a comma after your opts object, and I made the command the `true` command, just so there'd be something to run:

```
task('some_task_1', {async: true}, function () {
    console.log("|- Doing something");

    var command = "true";
    jake.exec(command, {}, function(){
        console.log("   |- Completed doing something");
        complete();
    });
});

task('some_task_2', {async: true}, function () {
    console.log("|- Doing something else");

    var command = "true";
    jake.exec(command, {}, function(){
        console.log("   |- Completed doing something else");
        complete();
    });
});

task('some_task_root', {async: true}, function () {
    var firstTask = jake.Task['some_task_1'];
    var secondTask = jake.Task['some_task_2'];

    firstTask.addListener("complete", function() { secondTask.invoke(); });
    secondTask.addListener("complete", function() { complete(); });

    firstTask.invoke();
});
```

That's all I changed, but I got the correct output, not what you describe:

```
$ jake some_task_root
|- Doing something
   |- Completed doing something
|- Doing something else
   |- Completed doing something else
```

Looks like you've also opened a GitHub Issue for this (https://github.com/mde/jake/issues/202), so let's resolve it over there on the Issue. The minimal example works correctly, so there must be something specific with your build script. Let's get some more details and try to get you sorted out. :)

Comment: I have updated the issue on there with a clearer example which exhibits the behavior on other computers which I could do with you checking over if you get a moment.